# doing an ajax request always outputs 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do an ajax request from my themes `header.php` file. I've read that I have to use the `admin-ajax.php` file to achieve this. So I looked for examples and found [this](https://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/) one.

My code in the `header.php` file looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test a').click(function(){
        var className = $(this).attr('class');

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
            data: {
                'action': 'myFunc',
                'id': className
            },
            success: function(res){
                alert(res);
            },
            error: function(err){
                alert("Error: " + err);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And my PHP code looks like this:

```
function myFunc() {
    echo "hello";
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myFunc', 'myFunc');
```

I'm not sure where I should put this PHP code. Should I put this in my `functions.php` file or directly to the `admin-ajax.php` file? It doesn't matter where I put the PHP code, the output is always 0 (the last line in `admin-ajax.php` is `die('0')`). Or is it because of my `url` parameter?

Comment: Have you considered using a REST API endpoint instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean and how a REST API could help to solve my problem. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Make sure you're logged out when testing the nopriv case.

Comment: @birgire I tested it with `nopriv` and without. Both of them doesn't work.

Comment: @Roman REST API endpoints are more structured and easier to work with, fewer pitfalls, and fewer steps to implement. The javascript part works the same, but the PHP part is simpler and more straight forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom functions should always go in your theme's `functions.php` file (if they are not within plugin territory). You should never try to modify any core files outside the `wp-content` folder (except `wp-config.php`) as they will be overridden by future updates.

Now, there are 2 ways to do what you want.

**1 - Admin-ajax**

This simple function will serve you nice to get a `hello!` as an output:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_handler', 'my_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_handler', 'my_ajax_handler');
function my_ajax_handler (){
    _e('Hello!','text-domain');
    exit();
}
```

Now, try and access the `admin-ajax.php` directly to see if you have an answer, by visiting `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_ajax_handler`. This should work for both logged-in and non-logged-in users.

**2 - REST-API**

Even simpler. Take a look into this:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    //Path to ajax function
    register_rest_route( 'Roman/v1', '/say_hello/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET', 
            'callback' => 'my_hello_function' 
    ) );
});
```

And a function to say hello:

```
function my_hello_function(){
    return __('Hello!','text-domain');
}
```

Now, if you send a request to `http://example.com/wp-json/Roman/v1/say_hello/`, you will get a nice welcome as JSON, like:

`{"Hello!"}`

Which you can use in your jQuery script.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I'll try them both. For the first way, should I put this function `my_ajax_handler()` into `functions.php` as you said, right? And what about my ajax request in `header.php`? Should I there request `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_ajax_handler` in the `url` parameter?

Comment: Okay I tested both and both works fine! I've seen that I just missed the `?action=` part in my request url. And I also had to move the function to `functions.php`. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Roman You are welcome. It seems you already figured it out yourself! nice. And yes, it all goes in `functions.php`. By the way, @TomJNowell really loves REST API, that's why he always recommends this over admin-ajax!

Comment: REST APIs are cool and very easy to use and I used it a few times for other projects, but I didn't know how to implement it in my case here.